# MQL4: can't workout how to get decimal value of 1/6

Tags: mql4

Can't work out why 1/6 keeps returning me 0 and how to resolve it.

```
Print(1/6);
Print(DoubleToString((1/6),8));
```

Prints 0.00000000

Comment: I don't even know what mql4 is, but clearly it does integer division.  Try `1.0/6`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, with all due respect, Sir, this is **not** an example of an **`MQL4`** language **integer division**, both of the above examples are out of any questions cases, where compile-time constants were evaluated and resulting values were hard-coded into the code-execution **`.MQ4`** file format, in which no division took place, but a compiler-generated fixed values were just presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one double number in expression. Try: `Print(1/6.0)`;

Answer (score 0):

### Why:

The code above presents a pair of constant ( that happen to be **`1`** and **`6`** in the posted case ).

The **`MQL4`** language is a compiled language and ( after expansion of #define macros, #include and similar pre-compilation steps have taken their place ) the compiler in the compilation phase "**reads**" your code and **lexically analyses, what is there intended to be done**.

Having seen an expression of `1 / 6`  in the code, the compiler knows, there is nothing that could change this part of code at runtime, inside the run-time ecosystem, and thus it tried to reduce this part of static-value code.

The compiler was hardwired so as to assemble the code-execution file-format ( an `.MQ4`-file ) into which it will -- no surprise in this -- put a straight `0`, as the compiler decided from the static code analysis -- a constant, derived from a compile-time known pair of integer literal constants `1` and `6`, not to waste a single nanosecond at runtime to ( re-)-evaluate the compile-time known value of `0`.

### How to resolve it:

```
double enumerator = 1,
       divisor    = 6;
Print(                 enumerator / divisor );
Print( DoubleToString( enumerator / divisor ),
                       8
                       )
       );
```